# Are there any anachronisms in Captain Marvel?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

*Captain Marvel* (2019) is set in 1995 [for some reason or other](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206993/why-did-marvel-set-captain-marvel-largely-in-the-1990s). During the movie, we see and hear various references to the time period: a *True Lies* ([July 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Lies)) cardboard cut-out in a Blockbuster Video store, posters for *Mellon Collie and the Infinite Sadness* ([October 1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellon_Collie_and_the_Infinite_Sadness)), and *Waterfalls* by TLC ([November 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrazySexyCool)) playing in Nick Fury's car.

Does anything appear in the movie that wasn't yet around in 1995?

Comment: The CD felt like one. I don't remember the exact year they were invented.

Comment: Scratch that. The first CD was released comercially in [1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD_player)

Comment: *snort* Kids. I bought my first Sony Discman in 1991 or so.

Comment: I'm wondering about Fury's Chevy Impala, I thought it looked to modern. I wondered about his Herman Miller Aero chair as well, but that was invented in the 80s.

Comment: There's a huge difference between the 6th Generation Impalas (1977-1985) and the 7th Generation onward (1995- ). It's really only the fact the '95 has a vertical grill instead of a sloped one and a longer trunk that makes it look significantly different from, say, a 2005.

Comment: It's not *impossible* chronologically (hence comment, not answer), but it was highly, highly unlikely for someone like Fury to have a black computer and keyboard in 1995. At that point in time, unless you really went out of your way to source the latest and greatest, your computer and keyboard would've been beige.

Comment: @martha The black computer equipment could have been SHIELD standard-issue.  I do recall seeing a keyboard in the background in the movie that seemed out of place; the keys seemed to have a lower profile similar to most of today's keyboards and unlike the 1992 IBM Model M I'm typing this on.  I'll have to look closer once I get the DVD.  It might have been Ok.

Comment: @Martha - Apple PowerBooks were dark grey / black at that time, also, the NeXT Cube / desktop was black as well, so there is chronological precendent for that color scheme - especially for a super secret org

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The movie *First Knight* is seen over Captain Marvel's right shoulder in the Blockbuster scene, but it was not released on VHS until December of 1995.

*Captain Marvel* is likely set sometime before this, as we see Stan Lee on a bus rehearsing his lines for *Mallrats*, which was released in October 1995.

Comment: “The movie was clearly set during the summer of that year.” Are we sure about that? It’s pretty sunny during the scenes in Los Angeles, but [that doesn’t appear to preclude it being December](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles#Climate).

Comment: To add to that: We see Stan Lee rehearsing his lines for Mallrats, which was released in October 1995. If it was still being filmed at that time, it has to be earlier than October at the very least.
Of course, Stan Lee's cameos may not be canon.

Comment: @GeorgeT: aha, excellent point. Technically for all we know, Stan is actually a really-long-lived Skrull in all his cameos, but I think we've got to take the references as they're laid out in the movie.

Comment: Couldn't Blockbuster have a promotional poster in the store some time before the actual release? That would seem like a sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 22):

Street Fighter II - Captain Marvel flashed back to playing that in 1989, but it came out in 1991.

Comment: Ah yes, excellent spot — although I think it's possible the flashback is to her playing whatever arcade game was in the same spot before being replaced by Street Fighter II.