# When has Captain Marvel previously listened to Nirvana?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

When Carol Danvers goes to talk to the Supreme AI after she recovers her memories, she plays the Nirvana song "Come as Your Are" which was released in 1991.

She had her accident in 1989 and they took her to the planet Hala.

How and when did she listen to Nirvana "Come as You Are" song, for it to be her favorite and be played in her mind, while speaking to the Supreme AI?

Comment: Your question could be an answer here.... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/206888/are-there-any-anachronisms-in-captain-marvel

Comment: I remember it being played on a record on her mind.

Comment: @Skooba The scene showed a turntable with the LP spinning inside the Supreme Intelligence simulation; it started just as the music came up.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Ah,yes, I forgot that part. Carry on, nothing to see here...

Comment: No-one said it was her favourite.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite but when did she even had a chance to remeber it?

She was not on earth when that song was released in 1991, she had the accident in 1989 and was taken to Hala.

Comment: @AlessandroSanfilippo: there's this clever thing with songs where they can actually still be played after they're released. So she heard it back on earth in 1995, as Zeiss Ikon has [explained below](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/207051/440).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the time of that scene, Carol had been back on Earth for some undisclosed time, traveling with Fury and talking to Marie Rambeau and her daughter "Lieutenant Trouble" -- it's entirely possible she heard the music during that period and liked it.  Preteens often tend to replay the same album almost continuously (in my experience); so if Monica liked Nirvana, there's no reason Carol wouldn't have had a chance to hear it multiple times (off screen).

I had writen that there was also an operating juke box in Pancho's, where Fury caught up with her after she stole the Harley, and she might have heard the song there, but I was reminded that she destroyed that juke box when she demonstrated her photonic blast to Fury.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I think when she is captured by Yon-Rogg and is hooked up the wire-like restraint is when the song plays, not in the beginning when she is first taken to the SI. Or at least what Zeiss is saying here. I personally don't remember which scene it was.

Comment: Ahh, now I see which scene is being discussed.

Comment: @Skooba you're correct, it was after Yon-Rogg and company had taken the Skrulls and humans by surprise.  There was no music in the first SI scene.

Comment: She might have heard it in the bar she visited too. I think we only hear Garbage's *I'm Only Happy When It Rains*, but I don't think we see the entirety of her time in there.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Thanks, that's a good point -- another time she might have heard it, since the juke box was playing and presumably she and Fury were there longer than three minutes.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Carol fires a neutron blast at the jukebox pretty early on in their conversation as proof she's not a Skrull, so it's not likely she heard the song coming from it in an off-camera moment there with Fury... though that doesn't preclude her hearing it elsewhere while on Earth, of course.

Comment: @TylerH: oh, yeah I forgot about destroying the jukebox. Which was a dick move! It was a nice jukebox!