# Could when did the post-credits sequence take place greatly affect the events of Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

This'll likely get canned as opinion based, but what the hey.

The "power core" as seen in captain marvel is give the name The Tesseract. While the events of this film precede the Avengers films, we "first" see Project Pegasus in Avengers (technically the post-credits sequence of Thor) - it's where Dr. Selvig is researching said Tesseract. This implies that they've had possession of it all those years.

But...

We see in Captain Marvel that Goose "ate" the Tesseract, and coughed it up in Fury's office a period of time later.

At the end of the film, it's clear that SHIELD consider the Tesseract lost - Coulson says they're looking for it, and Fury says he's sure it'll turn up. So clearly it shows up at some point later.

The question is, when did that event take place?

In the post-credits sequence, we're looking at an empty desk. the implication is that it’s empty because Fury’s been Snapped. Also, note that he’s got one of those modern web-back office chairs - they’d not been around for that many years - certainly not the 90s.

So there’s two possibilities ...

Goose coughed up the Tesseract some years ago, before the events of Thor, and they’ve been investigating it for a small number of years - Fury simply wasn’t at his desk when Goose did it.

OR...

He only did it very recently, which means there’s TWO Tesseracts - the one Thanos has, and this other one.

If that’s the case, the Avengers have access to a very powerful weapon.

Comment: I haven't seen the film yet but this question is rather unclear in its wording, could you go through and edit it up to be clearer?

Comment: Your assumptions about when the second post-credit event happened and the reason for Fury not being in his office are incorrect.

Comment: @Snow "Citation needed"

Comment: A modicum of Googling and [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97660/when-does-the-captain-marvel-post-credits-scene-take-place)

Comment: Which is exactly as much supposition and inference-making as mine. I prefer to have fun with topics like this.

Comment: Meet [The Aeron Chair](https://www.hermanmiller.com/products/seating/office-chairs/aeron-chairs/product-details/), available from Herman Miller since 1994.

Comment: And yes, the seat in the scene is an Aeron.

Comment: `"...the implication is that it’s empty because Fury’s been Snapped"` - This was not at all the implication. Also please edit your post to hide all the spoilers.

Comment: For a little on the Aeron's history, see http://nymag.com/news/intelligencer/21364/

Comment: This really isn't opinion based, but rather a faulty assumption.

Answer (score 6):

Based on evidence of the CRT monitor and the [Aeron chair](https://www.hermanmiller.com/products/seating/office-chairs/aeron-chairs/product-details/) in the post credit scene, we have to assume that the first of your scenarios is the right one.

This scene describes how the Tesseract ended up in the hands of the SHIELD research team.

Comment: As there are [several anachronisms in the film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/206888/58193) I don't think you can use the existence of something like that to say with confidence which is the case here.

Comment: Well, the chair was released for sale in 1994, so I'm pretty sure I could state that it's post 1994.  It's generally accepted that this scene was set shortly after the events of the main film.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: at best, we've got one-and-a-half anachronisms listed there.

Answer (score 2):

> “Before creation itself, there were six singularities. Then the universe exploded into existence, and the remnants of these systems were forged into concentrated ingots... Infinity Stones.”
>
> https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Stones#Creation

There's been no indication that anyone forged *duplicate* Infinity Stones. Given that the Space Stone seemed to work pretty well in *Avengers* (to open the portal) and *Infinity War* (to transport Thanos all over a galaxy or two), it's incredibly unlikely to have been a forgery.

The post-credits scene with Goose coughing up the Tesseract shows us that it *did* turn up, so it could end up in SHIELD's underground lab in *Avengers*. (As noted elsewhere, Aeron chairs first went on sale in the 90s, and  the monitor on the desk is also period-appropriate.)

What we *don't* yet know is how Mar-Vell originally got her hands on it, after Howard Stark pulled it out of the ocean at the end of *Captain America: The First Avenger*.

Comment: Your quote is from the Collector in GotG 1 IIRC so might be better to update this to point to the original and official source rather than some fan made wiki.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: is there an “official” source for MCU scripts?